# Reminders app doesn't show badges

Tags: applications, ios, notifications, reminders

I have a love-hate relationship with the new Reminders app in iOS 5.

I like how entering new items is made simple and the interface gradually reveals itself as you become more of a power user. Yet it fails at the most fundamental function—to remind me the important stuff that I entered.

How do I enable badges for due items in Reminders? I couldn't find the setting in Notifications preferences.

Does Reminders app support badges at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to, no: the Reminders app has neither its own  pane in the Settings app, nor any settings accessible in the app itself, and its entry under Notifications doesn't have an option to turn on Badges.

So, at least as of iOS 5.0.1, Reminders doesn't seem to support that feature.

I'm not seriously suggesting you switch apps, but if Badges in a todo app is a killer feature, I've also been a fan of [Things](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/things/id284971781?mt=8).

Comment: Yeah, in fact I was *hoping* to switch from Things to a simpler app but Reminders just doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

Recent iOS versions (at least 8 onwards) all support badges. The Notifications part of Settings allow you to control them in the same way as other apps.

However, it does appear that the app is a little buggy:

- Completion status often does not sync to other devices (often refreshing the Calendar app by pulling down on the list of calendars fixes this).
- Some reminders show on the lock screen (if enabled) but do not show a badge. My experience is that this only happens with location-based reminders.

Comment: So far iOS 10 seems considerably better with regard to syncing between devices